# Finding the max colour pixel based on the value in one channel in OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, comparison, mat

I'm starting manipulating images with OpenCV recently.

As far as I know, the cv::max(input1, input2, output) is used for finding the maximum BGR values of 2 images. I'd like to max within one colour channel, see the following example for 2 BGR mats (mat size 2x2):

`input1= [110, 100, 90, 109, 99, 89;
          111, 99, 89, 108, 98, 88]`

`inout2= [97, 141, 158, 95, 138, 157;
          98, 149, 169, 97, 148, 168]`

I want to max only the values in the blue channel, thus I will carry to my output mat whatsoever values for the green and red channels; thus I want the result to be like this:

`output= [110, 100, 90, 109, 99, 89;
          111, 99, 89, 108, 98, 88]`

Yes it happened to be that the output mat becomes a copy of input1, but please notice that running
`cv::max(input1, input2, output);` 
 gives

`output= [110, 141, 158, 109, 138, 157;
          111, 149, 169, 108, 148, 168]`

which somehow mixes the 2 mats channels.

Sorry for writing this long; I just wanted to be clear. Thank you,,,

UPDATE: I already implemented a solution using C++ for loops. Honestly they work but I'm looking for something faster and simpler, if any.

UPDATE2: From 2 input images, I need the max value from, say the blue channel, and store it into an output with its associate green and red values.

Answer (score 0):

You can split images, calculate max for the channels you want then you can merge it into a output array. Not much simpler but I think it is better than a classical for loop approach. In a limited time this is what I wrote, and it works as you want.

```
int ssz[2] = {2,2};

double data1[12] = {110,100,90,109,99,89,111,99,89,108,98,88}; 
double  data2[12] = {120,141,158,95,138,157,98,149,169,97,148,168};

Mat in1(2,ssz,CV_64FC3,data1);
Mat in2(2,ssz,CV_64FC3,data2);

Mat out = in1.clone();


Mat c1[3];      //0 indexes will be blue channel
Mat c2[3];
Mat oc[3];

split(in1,c1);
split(in2,c2);
split(out,oc);

cv::max(c1[0],c2[0],oc[0]);
cv::merge(oc,3,out);
```

To see it works I changed input2 ' s first element to 120. I tested and debuge, it works.

Comment: thank you for your effort, but your code answers something different. It does find the max in one channel, but it takes the associate green and red values only from in1 `Mat out = in1.clone()`.

Comment: Precisely, the first pixel in output is `120, 100, 90` based on the code, while it should be `120, 141, 158`. In fact, I'm expecting that pointers may do the job. But don't know how :D

Comment: I think you are having a confusion here. If you have a colored image it goes B,G,R respectively. So first pixel in the image will have 3 values BGR. And you wanted only blue channel to be maxed. So this is what you should get by maxing your input values, which is also same with you expected output.And one more thing, I assigned output to clone of input1 because you didnt say anything about output.You can take another 3 channel output array from somewhere else,split it,use max on the first channel(blue) than merge it again.It will again work and max the blue channel onto blue channel of output

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry that my request isn't this clear. I'm not only finding the max in one channel; I want its associate values in the other channels unchanged and store this pixel into an output mat. In your code, let's look at the BGR pixels (0,0) in in1 (`110, 100, 90`) and in2 (`120, 141, 158`). My request is to pick the pixel (with its BGR values intact) in in2 as the max and place it in an output mat because its value, say in the blue channel, is greater than the blue value in in1 (110<120), although this is not necessary for the other two channels.

Comment: I ran your code and it gives me (`120, 100, 90`) in the output mat; I believe the 120 from in2 while 100 and 90 from in1 since they were copied with `in1.clone()` previously. I changed it to `in2.clone()` and it went okay with pixel (0,0), but the other pixels were not :)

Comment: So you want max values of blue channels of in1 and in2; and you want to keep the green and red values of in1. So then basically you should do what I did above :) To keep green and red channels of in1 you first clone it and use max on the blue channel in this cloned Mat

Comment: No sir; the green and red values that associate the max value in blue; either from in1 or in2. This should be explaining the title: the max colour pixel based on the value in one channel" :)

Comment: Ok now I understood your question :) It was really hard to understand what you wanted with your supplied example. You want BGR values of output from which has the max blue value either in1 or in2. There is not a ready to use function for these. But I think it can be implemented using iterators etc; unfortunately I dont know how to use them :) Your for loop solution would be much easier to understand also.

Answer (score 0):

I made this using the classic C++ for loop, which is all what I'm good for :D However, I'm still expecting a better answer at least regarding avoiding `.at` .

```
int imdepth=CV_32F;
Mat outBlue (2, 2, imdepth);
Mat outGreen (2, 2, imdepth);
Mat outRed (2, 2, imdepth);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        float blue1 = in1b.at<float>(i,j);   //in1b, in2b, in1g, etc. are
        float blue2 = in2b.at<float>(i,j);   //channels from img1 and img2
        if (blue1>blue2) {
            outBlue.at<float>(i,j)  = blue1;
            outGreen.at<float>(i,j) = in1g.at<float>(i,j);
            outRed.at<float>(i,j)   = in1r.at<float>(i,j);
        } else {
            outBlue.at<float>(i,j)  = blue2;
            outGreen.at<float>(i,j) = in2g.at<float>(i,j);
            outRed.at<float>(i,j)   = in2r.at<float>(i,j);
        }
    }
}
vector<Mat> out(3);
out[0]  = outBlue;
out[1]  = outGreen;
out[2]  = outRed;
Mat output (2, 2, CV_32FC3);
merge (out, output);
```

Comment: @yutasrobot: please look at my code that it may give you a clue. Suggestions are welcome :)